# AA Travel Voucher from 2000 and 2001

Tags: transportation, vouchers

I have a couple unused travel vouchers from prior to 2002, can I still use it, how do I exchange it and what are fees if any?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely— almost all airline vouchers are good for one year or less from the date of issue. But just in case, what voucher type is it? Do you remember why it was issued to you?

Comment: Have you considered asking AA?

Answer (score 3):

From [American Airlines](http://www.american-airlines.nl/intl/be/agency/bookingAndTicketing.jsp#) (click on 'Transportation Vouchers'):

> **Validity**
>
> Transportation vouchers will be valid for one year from the date of issue unless otherwise noted. Once expired they will not
>   be honoured for reissue or exchange to a new voucher

so essentially, no, they're not valid.  However if you phone or see them in person and get the right supportive customer service agent, you never know - they may be prepared to re-issue them.